# Ошибка после установки ubuntu "symbol not found: 'grub_env_export"

Tags: ubuntu

> error: symbol not found: 'grub_env_export'.grub rescue>

После установки `ubuntu` выводит такое, что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Восстановление GRUB с LiveCD в chroot

- sudo fdisk -l
- sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
- sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
- sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
- sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
- sudo chroot /mnt
- grub-install /dev/sda (если сообщение об ошибке - grub-install --recheck /dev/sda)
- exit
- sudo umount /mnt/dev
- sudo umount /mnt/proc
- sudo umount /mnt
- sudo reboot

sda и соответственно sda1 это первый раздел на "первом" диске, где у Вас установлен linux я не знаю, по этому значения sdX и sdXX могут быть другими.

Comment: Благодарю =)